# not able to display footer using TOM and javascript in mozila

Tags: javascript

How to diplay footer like this in mozilla?

```
<html>
<TABLE ID="oTable_1" BORDER="0" BGCOLOR="lightslategray" width=100% >
<TBODY ID="oTBody0_1"></TBODY>
<TBODY ID="oTBody0_2"></TBODY></TABLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

var oTHead = oTable_1.createTHead();
var oTFoot = oTable_1.createTFoot();
var oCaption = oTable_1.createCaption();
var oRow, oCell;

//code  to display table body
//but when i am displayin footer its not displaying in mozila ..working in chrome and IE

oRow = oTFoot.insertRow();
oCell = oRow.insertCell();
oCell.innerHTML = '<center> hi mozilla </center>' ;
oCell.colSpan = "12";
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
oRow = oTFoot.insertRow(-1);
oCell = oRow.insertCell(-1)
```

The [index argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.insertRow) is not optional for `insertRow()` and `insertCell()`:

> If `index` is -1 or equal to the number
>   of rows, the row is appended as the
>   last row. **If `index` is omitted or
>   greater than the number of rows, an
>   error will result.**